# Applying Master's Theorem to a recurrence of type $T(n) = \sqrt{2} \cdot T (n/2) + \log (n)$

Tags: algorithms

I have a recurrence of type and I am trying to solve it with the Master's Theorem:

> $T(n) = \sqrt{2} \cdot T (n/2) + \log (n)$

I just tried to solve it by substituting $m = \log (n)$ such that the new equation becomes:

> $T(2^m) = \sqrt{2} \cdot T (2^m/2) + m$

Then I tried to substitute

> $S(m) = T(2^m)$

but then I ran into confusion about how to transform $T (2^m/2)$ using this, could anyone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $$T (2^m/2) =T (2^{m-1})=S(m-1)$$ hence the transformed recursion reads $$S(m)=c\,S(m-1)+m,$$ for some $c\gt1$, to which the methods you know might apply.

Comment: Ah, thank you so much! So, the master theorem does not apply here, since b = 1 .

Comment: No--either you want to apply the so-called Master theorem and then you stick to the original recursion on T, with a=sqrt(2) and b=2, or you transform the equation using S and then you forget the Master theorem altogether and solve directly. My answer explains the latter route. The former route is direct applying [the proper case](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem#Generic_form_2).

Comment: Okay, suppose I want to apply the Master's Theorem, how can I compare n ^ logb(a) = n^1/2 in this case with log(n) since they don't have any equivalence in terms of base of n ? Could you please help with that ?

Comment: You misread: the condition is that $f(n)$ (in your case, $\log n$) is $O(n^c)$ (in your case, $O(n^{1/2})$), not that $f(n)=\Theta(n^c)$. Since $\log n=O(n^d)$ for every $d\gt0$, the MT fully applies to your case.

Comment: Could you please explain a bit further, how does log (n) imply O(n^d) ? Does it mean that log n is always bounded from above by n^d ? And if so, how can we automatically compare it with O (n^(1/2-E)) which is what we do in the first case, no ?

Comment: Sorry but this is basic (and much needed to anybody interested in complexity classes) hence I suggest you check the WP pages on O(.) classes.

Comment: Okay, I'll check it out, and then try to figure it out, thanks for your help!